# How do I link to a phone number in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

Whenever I use the default Linking.openURL, I get an unhandled promise rejection. When I use the {phonecall} from https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications, I get Can't handle url: tel:4159955552 (a random restaurant's phone #)

```
  phonecall("4159955552", false);
  Linking.openURL("tel:4159955552");
```

Comment: You need to use a real device to make it work, and maybe replace `tel:` with `telprompt:` in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Using `{phonecall}` from react-native-communications worked. It just can't be from the IOS simulator.